# How to create scope for parent fragment to use it in children

Tags: koin, koin-scope, android-koin

I have a class `TestClass` and I want to share its instance between child fragment with using **koin scope** of parent fragment.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks.

I try:

```
class TestClass {
    fun close() { .... }
}

class ParentFragment(): Fragment  { }

val testModule = module {
    scope<ParentFragment> {
         scopedOf(::TestClass).onClose { it?.close() } 
    }
}

class Child1Fragment : Fragment  {
    private val testClass: TestClass by inject() // What I should write here?!

}

class Child2Fragment : Fragment  {
    private val testClass: TestClass by inject()

}

class Child3Fragment : Fragment  {
    private val testClass: TestClass by inject()

}
```